# android hacer calculos automaticos desde un edit text a otro

Tags: android

me han pedido hacer un programa en android el cual sea capaz de convertir de grados Fahrenheit a grados celcius y viceversa, hasta aqui todo facil, pero, me pregunte si es posible hacer que al poner por ejemplo 1 en grados celcius me presente automaticamente su valor correspondiente en grados Fahrenheit. Existe alguna forma de hacerlo?

este es mi codigo logico para mi aplicacion, la cual necesito darle a Enter para que calcule la equivalencia

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private EditText f,c;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    f = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_f);
    c = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_c);

    c.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            Double gf = ((1.8)*Double.parseDouble(c.getText().toString()))+32;
            f.setText(""+gf);

            return false;

        }

    });

    f.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            Double gc = (Double.parseDouble(f.getText().toString())-32)/1.8;
            c.setText(""+gc);

            return false;

        }

    });


}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Deberias cambiar los EditorActionListener por TextWatcher asi no necesitarias tocar enter para que ejecute el calculo.

```
c.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int count, int after) {}

   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int before, int count) {
      if(c.hasFocus()){
         try {
            Double gf = ((1.8)*Double.parseDouble(c.getText().toString()))+32;
            f.setText(""+gf);
         }
         catch(Exception e) {
            //Error de parseo 
         }
      }
   }
});

f.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int count, int after) {}

   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int before, int count) {
      if(f.hasFocus()){
         try{
            Double gc = (Double.parseDouble(f.getText().toString())-32)/1.8;
            c.setText(""+gc);
         }
         catch(Exception e) {
            //Error de parseo 
         }
      }
   }
});
```

Ademas le agregue una validacion con el hasFocus para que solo realize el calculo cuando el texto cambie por el input y no porque se modifico por el cambio del otro EditText, evitando que entre en un loop.

Comment: hay que agregar el Double gf ... dentro de un try-catch para evitar una excepcion

Comment: si, tenes razon gracias, lo edito y lo agrego, no habia prestado atencion al calculo porque entendia que lo tenia resuelto.

Comment: muchas gracias por sus respuestas, ahora me pongo las pilas para terminar este proyecto